# SharePoint 2013 Windows Extranet Permisisons

Tags: permissions, active-directory

I have inherited a SharePoint site as part of a new job. The thing is a bit of a mess but I'm getting my head around it.

The previous admin has created an extranet which uses a Basic Windows Authentication challenge. So 'external' users are given an account and they can log in directly to a sub site on SharePoint to do their collaboration activities.

For some reason authentication doesn't work consistently across devices. I have been able to log in from my home network but not using my iPhone or iPad.

Also SharePoint doesn't seem to allow users in an AD Group (extranet_users) that is added the SharePoint Site_Members Group to access the site.

Can anyone throw me a few  pointers on how to work out what's happening.